# Android NDK Crash on Emulator

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am really new to Android especially with NDK. I tried to load samples like the hello-jni and it worked perfectly. However, when I tried to code my own, when I build it using the ndk-build command, it didn't have any problems. But when I tried to call the class from my java code and have it compiled, it crashes on emulator. I don't know what's the problem because what I did is copy the codes from the hello-jni sample and replaced some with mine, but it is not working. Please I really need your help.

My Android.mk

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE    := AndroidProject
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AndroidProject.c

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My AndroidProject.c

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <jni.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

   int s_ButtonPressCounter = 0;

   jstring
   Java_com_example_AndroidProject_AndroidProject_invokeNativeFunction()( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject thiz )
   {
    char szBuf[512];
    sprintf(szBuf, " You have pressed this huge button %d times", s_ButtonPressCounter++);

   jstring str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, szBuf);
   return str;
   }
```

My AndroidProject.java

```
  package com.example.androidproject;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class AndroidProject extends Activity {


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Create a Button and set its content.
         * the text is retrieved by calling a native
         * function.
         */
        TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText( invokeNativeFunction() );
        setContentView(tv);

    }

    public native String  invokeNativeFunction();

     static {
        System.loadLibrary("AndroidProject");
    }

    }
```

The Logcat:

Here is the LogCat:

```
09-24 22:19:00.369: E/Trace(823): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-24 22:19:00.819: D/dalvikvm(823): Trying to load lib /data/app- lib/com.example.androidproject-2/libndktest.so 0x40cdf458
09-24 22:19:00.839: D/dalvikvm(823): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.androidproject-2/libndktest.so 0x40cdf458
09-24 22:19:00.839: D/dalvikvm(823): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.androidproject-2/libndktest.so 0x40cdf458, skipping init
09-24 22:19:01.529: W/dalvikvm(823): No implementation found for native Lcom/example/androidproject/AndroidProject;.invokeNativeFunction:()Ljava/lang/String;
09-24 22:19:01.529: D/AndroidRuntime(823): Shutting down VM
09-24 22:19:01.539: W/dalvikvm(823): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.androidproject.AndroidProject.invokeNativeFunction:()Ljava/lang/String;
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at com.example.androidproject.AndroidProject.invokeNativeFunction(Native Method)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at com.example.androidproject.AndroidProject.onCreate(AndroidProject.java:27)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can we see your Logcat please?

Comment: The logcat has been posted. I really don't know what to do with this.

Comment: @jww - sorry about that. i'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this from your logcat:

```
09-24 22:19:01.559: E/AndroidRuntime(823): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:
com.example.androidproject.AndroidProject.invokeNativeFunction:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

First, it looks like `invokeNativeFunction` is a copy paste/error from your previous project. Since you are not using it, delete its declaration.

Second, it looks like you need to run `javah` on your compiled Java code to produce a header with proper function names. To do so:

1. Perform a ***Build All*** to have Java generate the class files
2. Open a terminal
3. Change into your `bin` directory
4. Run `javah` on AndroidProject:

   ```
   javah -o ../jni/AndroidProject.h classes/com/example/AndroidProject/AndroidProject
   ```
5. Include `AndroidProject.h` in `AndroidProject.c`
6. Perform a ***Build All*** to ensure the new shared object is built and packaged

Comment: About the invokeNativeFuction , I got that one wrong. I replaced the stringfromJNI from my java and C code to invokeNativeFunction and build it again. The same as before it went well, but has the same error after running it on emulator.

Comment: I don't know how to do the second that you said. Could you give me more details how to do this? Sorry about the inconvenience, I'm just new to this stuff.

Comment: @John Anothony - are you running Windows?

Comment: Yes I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java expects C function name

```
Java_com_example_androidproject_AndroidProject_invokeNativeFunction
```

so it looks like a simple naming issue.